# Best way to convert time format from Feb 05 2020 01:55 pm to 2020-02-05 13:55:00

Tags: python, csv, awk, sed

What would be the best way to convert this date-time form:

```
Feb 05 2020   09:26 am
Feb 05 2020   01:55 pm
```

into

```
2020-02-05 09:26:00
2020-02-05 13:55:00
```

I know I can used sed to go through the iterations on the day change to the 2020-02-05 format.
I could use:

```
echo "01:55 pm" | sed -e 's/01:\([0-9]\+\) pm/13:\1:00/g'
```

to iterate through the file for different times.

Would this be the best way to handle it?
I'm opening to using python or another method if it works more cleanly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use for example the module `datetime` and the function `strptime`.
You should check the Python reference for [strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes):

> classmethod `datetime.strptime(date_string, format)`
>
> Return a datetime corresponding to date_string, parsed according to format.

```
from datetime import datetime
str1 = 'Feb 05 2020   09:26 am'
str2 = 'Feb 05 2020   01:55 pm'

date_1 = datetime.strptime(str1, "%b %d %Y    %I:%M %p")
date_2 = datetime.strptime(str2, "%b %d %Y    %I:%M %p")

print("date =", date_1)
print("date =", date_2)
```

Result:

```
date = 2020-02-05 09:26:00
date = 2020-02-05 13:55:00
```

Comment: Thanks for all of the possible solutions. I ended up going with the Python one as it will serve me better moving forward.

Answer (score 2):

use the built-in function to parse strings into datetime objects:

```
from datetime import datetime

s = 'Feb 05 2020   09:26 am'
d = datetime.strptime(s, '%b %d %Y   %I:%M %p')
print(d)
print(type(d))
```

will print

```
2020-02-05 09:26:00
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Comment: You are using `%H`. I believe that this will give the wrong answer for pm despite the use of %p - the `%I` for a 12-hour clock should be used in conjunction with `%p`.

Comment: correct. will delete this post as your answer covers this already

Comment: As you wish, but your answer has the interesting observation that the output format is just the usual string representation of the datetime object (no actual need for `strftime` on output), so it would be worth correcting and keeping it because I missed that fact.

Comment: ok I corrected it to not provide wrong answers

Comment: Good. I think it is worth keeping both answers so that the OP can see the fact that `strftime` is not actually necessary here, but nonetheless how to use it if a slightly different output format were needed.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS="[ :]"
  num=split("jan,feb,mar,apr,may,jun,jul,aug,sep,oct,nov,dec",arr,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    month[arr[i]]=i
  }
}
{
  printf("%d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:00\n",$3,month[tolower($1)],$2,$(NF-2)+$NF=="pm" && $(NF-2)<12 ? 12 : 0 ),$(NF-1))
}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above solution.

```
awk '                            ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                           ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.
  FS="[ :]"                      ##Setting field separator as space and colon here.
  num=split("jan,feb,mar,apr,may,jun,jul,aug,sep,oct,nov,dec",arr,",")   ##Creating array arr which has all months names in it.
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){           ##Starting for loop from 1 to till value of arr length here.
    month[arr[i]]=i              ##Creating month array with index of value of arr with index i and its value is variable i.
  }
}
{
  printf("%d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:00\n",$3,month[tolower($1)],$2,$(NF-2)+($NF=="pm" && $(NF-2)<12 ? 12 : 0 ),$(NF-1))   ##Printing 3rd field, month value with first field as index, 2nd field, 2nd last field and adding 12 if last field is pm else do not add anything.
}'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the conversion functions in `datetime` (see [format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)):

```
import datetime

in_format = '%b %d %Y   %I:%M %p'
out_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
value = 'Feb 05 2020   01:55 pm'

print(datetime.datetime.strptime(value, in_format).strftime(out_format))
```

Gives:

```
2020-02-05 13:55:00
```